# how to create Google cloud compute instance with multiple public IP and multiple private IP

Tags: networking, interface, gcloud

I have create private subnet on gcloud. Now I want to start gcloud instance with multiple private static IP and one public IP.but there no option for creating such VM. Please help if you know. Better if you post gcloud SDK command for it.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look around and take the [tour], and read through the [help center]. You can also read about [ask] a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `gcloud compute instances create` command use the `--private-network-ip=`*IP-ADDRESS* flag to assign one internal/static IP. Only one is supported.